# jquery animate function not stable

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate

I have a simple animate function, its working but when mouse hover/leave quick its unstable/(or not working properly). Specially in mouse leave remove() function not work some time. Do quick mouse work there you'll find the problem

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#social_link1').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).animate({
        width: '+=130px',
    }, 200, '', function () {
       if(jQuery(this).children('span').length < 1){
                jQuery(this).append('<span>ফেইসবুকে আমরা</span>');
        }
    });


}, function () {
    jQuery(this).children('span').remove();
    jQuery(this).animate({
        width: '-=130px',
    });

});

jQuery('#social_link2').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).animate({
        width: '+=130px',
    }, 200, '', function () {
       if(jQuery(this).children('span').length < 1){
                         jQuery(this).append('<span>টুইটারে আমরা</span>');
                 }
    });


}, function () {
    jQuery(this).children('span').remove();
    jQuery(this).animate({
        width: '-=130px',
    });

});

jQuery('#social_link1,#social_link2').mouseleave(function(){
           jQuery(this).children('span').remove();
     });
});
```

see details
https://jsfiddle.net/e2txv8a6/

Comment: use `stop(true, true)`  https://jsfiddle.net/e2txv8a6/1/

Answer (score 0):

there is also a ["mouseenter"](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and ["mouseleave"](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) function in jquery. so it triggers only on entering the element and leaving the element.

but in your case i would recommend doing it with pure css cause thats much better for performance issues and its also easier to manage.

you can achieve that by using [css transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

for that case i updated your fiddle with a css transition.

```
-webkit-transition:width 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition:width 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

[see updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2txv8a6/2/)

greetings timmi

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But css3 perhaps will create browser issue. My jquery is working fine now

Comment: yay but just in i.e. <= 9 http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions  ... but as long as it works... its nice ;)